# Tesseract 3.04 PDF Output is Blue

Tags: linux, pdf, ocr, tesseract, suse

### Background

I am using Tesseract-OCR 3.04 on a Linux setup to batch OCR process for a bunch of non-searchable PDFs.

My process is such that I take the `PDF`, convert it to a `tiff` format, then using Tesseract, I convert that `tiff` into a searchable `pdf` format.

### The issue

The output from the Tesseract 3.04 `tiff` to `pdf` conversion always produces a `pdf` with a blue background. I have checked and the `tiff` file has a white background.

Here is the output I am getting. Obviously mostly-censored for privacy.
[image: Actual output]

### What I have tried

- I have created by own "untouched" tiff file with a white background and ran it through Tesseract to a `pdf` output and the blue background persists. I did this by typing paragraphs of text into my text editor, screenshotting it, and converting it to tiff.
- I have had absolutely no results in google searching my issue.

### --

I do not know what the issue is within the Tesseract process, does anyone have any information that could help?

Thanks!